# How to edit the rules in wso2 brs or wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb 4.8.0 the very new version
using this i write a proxy which includes **rule meditor** so my rule mediator is perfectly fine i am happy with that.The issue is if client wish to change his rules how he can do this.
Where as in **Orcle soa bussiness rule** client can edit the rules using **orcle composer** in wso2 we have any option like that
For this i used wso2BRS server also it is also working fine but again same issue server also don't have any edit option
if i am wrong please guide me for this

Answer (score 0):

For editing rules, you need drools (by JBoss). You can add this feature from the Marketplace by selecting JBoss tools.

Jeroen